# Detect segment intersections with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, ifthenelse, totalcount

I have to detect when two segments intersect in a parametric figure that need's to computes coordinates into a tikz picture, and it won't works, seem's that "intersections=... total=\t" or "\equal{\t}{1}" don't have desired result.

Je doit détecter quand 2 segments se croisent dans un dessin paramétrique qui à besoin de calculer des coordonnées dans une image tikz. Mais ça ne fonctionne pas. J'ai l'impression que soit "total=\t" dans la calcul de l'intersection, soit mon test de comparaison de \t avec 1 n'ont pas le comportement attendu.

The code / Le code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [name path=l1] (-3,-3) -- (6,4);
  \draw [name path=l2] (-2,2) -- (2,-2);
  \path [name intersections={of=l1 and l2,name=int,total=\t}];
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\t}{1}}{
    \coordinate [label=I] (I) at (int-1);
  }{}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

nor / ni

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [name path=l1] (-3,-3) -- (6,4);
  \draw [name path=l2] (-2,2) -- (2,-2);
  \path [name intersections={of=l1 and l2,by=I}, 
         every node/.style={label=I}];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Do not print the I label, so I guess that no coordinate is created. / N'affiche pas le label de I, alors je suppose qu'aucun coordonée n'est créée.

But the code / Alors que le code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [name path=l1] (-3,-3) -- (6,4);
  \draw [name path=l2] (-2,2) -- (2,-2);
  \path [name intersections={of=l1 and l2,name=int}];
  \coordinate [label=I] (I) at (int-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Show the I point label or fail when segments does'nt intersect. / Affiche bien le label du point I ou plante si les segments ne se recoupent pas.

How can I either capture the "total" value, either catch the failure ?

Comment puis-je soit récupérer la valeur "total", soit rattraper l'erreur ?

EDIT: Complete script as asked.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [name path=l1] (-2,-3) -- (4,2);
  \draw [name path=l2] (-1,2) -- (2,-2);
  \path [name intersections={of=l1 and l2,name=int,total=\t}];
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\t}{1}}{
    \coordinate [label=I] (I) at (int-1);
  }{}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [name path=l3] (-2,-3) -- (4,2);
  \draw [name path=l4] (-1,2) -- (2,-2);
  \path [name intersections={of=l3 and l4,by=I},
         every node/.style={label=I}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [name path=l5] (-2,-3) -- (4,2);
    \draw [name path=l6] (-1,2) -- (2,-2);
    %\draw [name path=l6] (-1,2) -- (-2,-2); % non intersect = failure
  \path [name intersections={of=l5 and l6,name=inter}];
  \coordinate [label=J] (J) at (inter-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I need coordinate "I" to be created in the first intersection, (as J was in the third) but I need to avoid failure when segments don't intersect.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your diagram.

Comment: Thanks Zarko. 
I've edited the original post with a complete script. Is that what you needs ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Seem's I've an answer.

\ifthenelse{} into tikzpicture env requires to be outside path instructions. So at compilation time pdftex requires to end the path with a ";", and so the intersections.total attribute reference is closed.

But \ifnum{} works perfectly.

My solution is:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % 2 segments that intersect = node I
  \draw [name path=l1] (-2,2) -- (2,1.5);
  \draw [name path=l2] (-2,1.5) -- (2,2);
  \path [name intersections={of=l1 and l2, name=i, total=\t}]
        \ifnum \t=1 (i-1) node [style=above] {I} \fi;

  % 2 parallel segments = no intersection = no node J and no compilation failure
  \draw [name path=l3] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
  \draw [name path=l4] (-2,0.2) -- (2,0.2);
  \path [name intersections={of=l3 and l4, name=i, total=\t}]
        \ifnum \t=1 (i-1) node [style=above] {J} \fi;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```